# SQLite: select MIN from limited row set

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to select min ID value from top 5 rows in the table. I get top IDs with this query:

```
SELECT id FROM items ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

It works fine and returns ID values from top 5 rows:

```
314
313
312
311
310
```

Now, trying to get the minimal ID from this set:

```
SELECT MIN(id) FROM items ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

I expect the result to be **310** but SQLite return **1**.
What's up with that? Where am I wrong and do I achieve my goal?

**UPDATE:**

`SELECT MIN(id) FROM (SELECT id FROM news_items ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5)` works, so now I'm just curious about what's wrong with the first query.

Comment: So, are you actually using `MAX`?, should it be `MIN` instead?. And to answer your question, what is the minimum `id` on your table?

Comment: @Lamak: sorry, I am using `MIN` everywhere in my code, it's just the question that was messed up (now fixed). Minimum id on my table is indeed **1**.

Comment: your minimum value is `1`?, and the result of your first query is `0`?, then my answer is not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are actually using `MIN` instead of `MAX`, then the explanation is very simple. The `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5` is the last part that gets evaluated on your query. So, on your first query, you are retrieving the minimum value for `id` (it should be `0`), then the `ORDER BY ....` is irrelevent (you are ordering and limiting just one row)

Comment: Okay, so I guess it's just a hole in my understanding of how SQL works, thank you

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY` requires the entire data set to be evaluated in order to get the sorting correct.

Through empirical evidence we can assume `MIN` is evaluated at each row. :)

Comment: Is that true even when the column is indexed?